# Trying to make progress bar move incrementally

Tags: javascript

How can I make my progress bar show in increments based on my question number. Currently it completes to 100% after clicking the next question button. But, I am trying to let it increase in the increments of the question numbers and go backwards if the previous question button is clicked. The codepen with all the code is [here](https://codepen.io/centem/pen/ExKGOWj). Thank you.

```
  var i = 0;
  function moveForward() {
    if (i == 0) {
      i = 1;
      var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
      var width = 10;
      var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
      function frame() {
        if (width >= 100) {
          clearInterval(id);
          i = 0;
        } else {
          width++;
          elem.style.width = width + "%";
          elem.innerHTML = width + "%";
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  function moveBackward() {
    if (i == 0) {
      i = 1;
      var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
      var width = 10;
      var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
      function frame() {
        if (width >= 100) {
          clearInterval(id);
          i = 0;
        } else {
          width++;
          elem.style.width = width + "%";
          elem.innerHTML = width + "%";
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

///// UPDATED FUNCTION

```
  function moveForward(i) {
    console.log('i: ' + i);
    var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
    switch(i) {
      case 0:
        elem.style.width = "33%";
        elem.innerHTML = "33%";
        break;
      case 1:
        elem.style.width = "66%";
        elem.innerHTML = "66%";
        break;
      case 2:
        elem.style.width = "100%";
        elem.innerHTMl = "100%";
    }
  }
```

Comment: Reason why move backward increases the width?

Comment: Don't use an interval if you only want to adjust it one degree of completion.

Comment: Well you run an interval until it gets to the new width... and new width ends at 100%??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it is completing after one click is that `setInterval` runs the function repetitively every x milliseconds. That means that your `frame` function runs every 10 milliseconds until it hits the if statement that clears the interval. Since your stop check only stops at `width >= 100` it continues to expand until it is set to 100%.

In order to properly track the existing and next widths you will need to have a persistent variable in a global scope and you'll need to pass a target width to `frame` so that it knows when to actually stop

There are two other issues with your code. The first is that the previous button also increases the width rather than decreasing it, and the other issue is that every time you click the next or previous buttons it first resets the width to 10 and then increases it to 100.

Comment: Thanks for the hits Kevin. I updated the question with what I'm experimenting with. It still doesn't work like I want but I can post a new question about some specific issues.